# Syntax Error Debuging with big query

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I am working with the Riot Games API and I am currently trying to save the users recent games to my database for later processing.

Here is my current query.

```
$dbh = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO recent_games (

            gameId, invalid, gameMode, gameType, subType, mapId, teamId, championId, spell1, spell2, level, ipEarned, createDate, 
            summonerId0, teamId0, championId0, 
            summonerId1, teamId1, championId1, 
            summonerId2, teamId2, championId2,
            summonerId3, teamId3, championId3,
            summonerId4, teamId4, championId4,
            summonerId5, teamId5, championId5,
            summonerId6, teamId6, championId6,
            summonerId7, teamId7, championId7,
            summonerId8, teamId8, championId8,
            ingame_level, goldEarned, numDeaths, 
            turretsKilled, minionsKilled, championsKilled, 
            totalDamageDealt, totalDamageTaken, doubleKills, 
            killingSprees, largestKillingSpree, team, win, 
            neutralMinionsKilled, largestMultiKill,
            physicalDamageDealtPlayer, magicDamageDealtPlayer, 
            physicalDamageTaken, magicDamageTaken, 
            largestCriticalStrike, timePlayed, totalHeal,
            totalUnitsHealed, assists, item0, item1, item2, 
            item3, item4, item5, item6, magicDamageDealtToChampions, 
            physicalDamageDealtToChampions, totalDamageDealtToChampions, 
            trueDamageDealtPlayer, 
            trueDamageDealtToChampions, trueDamageTaken, 
            wardPlaced, neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle, 
            neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle, totalTimeCrowdControlDealt

        )VALUES(

            :gameId, 
            :invalid, 
            :gameMode, 
            :gameType, 
            :subType, 
            :mapId, 
            :teamId, 
            :championId, 
            :spell1, 
            :spell2, 
            :level, 
            :ipEarned, 
            :createDate, 
            :summonerId0, 
            :teamId0, 
            :championId0, 
            :summonerId1, 
            :teamId1, 
            :championId1, 
            :summonerId2, 
            :teamId2, 
            :championId2,
            :summonerId3, 
            :teamId3, 
            :championId3,
            :summonerId4, 
            :teamId4, 
            :championId4,
            :summonerId5, 
            :teamId5, 
            :championId5,
            :summonerId6, 
            :teamId6, 
            :championId6,
            :summonerId7, 
            :teamId7, 
            :championId7,
            :summonerId8, 
            :teamId8, 
            :championId8,
            :ingame_level, 
            :goldEarned, 
            :numDeaths, 
            :turretsKilled, 
            :minionsKilled, 
            :championsKilled, 
            :totalDamageDealt, 
            :totalDamageTaken, 
            :doubleKills, 
            :killingSprees, 
            :largestKillingSpree, 
            :team, 
            :win, 
            :neutralMinionsKilled, 
            :largestMultiKill,
            :physicalDamageDealtPlayer, 
            :magicDamageDealtPlayer, 
            :physicalDamageTaken, 
            :magicDamageTaken, 
            :largestCriticalStrike, 
            :timePlayed, 
            :totalHeal,
            :totalUnitsHealed, 
            :assists, 
            :item0, 
            :item1, 
            :item2, 
            :item3, 
            :item4, 
            :item5, 
            :item6, 
            :magicDamageDealtToChampions, 
            :physicalDamageDealtToChampions, 
            :totalDamageDealtToChampions, 
            :trueDamageDealtPlayer, 
            :trueDamageDealtToChampions, 
            :trueDamageTaken, 
            :wardPlaced, 
            :neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle, 
            :neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle, 
            :totalTimeCrowdControlDealt

        ");
        $dbh->execute(array(
            "gameId" => $data['gameId'],
            "invalid" => $data['invalid'],
            "gameMode" => $data['gameMode'],
            "gameType" => $data['gameType'],
            "subType" => $data['subType'],
            "mapId" => $data['mapId'],
            "teamId" => $data['teamId'],
            "teamId" => $data['teamId'],
            "championId" => $data['championId'],
            "spell1" => $data['spell1'],
            "spell2" => $data['spell2'],
            "level" => $data['level'],
            "ipEarned" => $data['ipEarned'],
            "createDate" => $data['createDate'],
            "summonerId0" => $data['fellowPlayers'][0]['summonerId'],
            "teamId0" => $data['fellowPlayers'][0]['teamId'],
            "championId0" => $data['fellowPlayers'][0]['championId'],
            "summonerId1" => $data['fellowPlayers'][1]['summonerId'],
            "teamId1" => $data['fellowPlayers'][1]['teamId'],
            "championId1" => $data['fellowPlayers'][1]['championId'],
            "summonerId2" => $data['fellowPlayers'][2]['summonerId'],
            "teamId2" => $data['fellowPlayers'][2]['teamId'],
            "championId2" => $data['fellowPlayers'][2]['championId'],
            "summonerId3" => $data['fellowPlayers'][3]['summonerId'],
            "teamId3" => $data['fellowPlayers'][3]['teamId'],
            "championId3" => $data['fellowPlayers'][3]['championId'],
            "summonerId4" => $data['fellowPlayers'][4]['summonerId'],
            "teamId4" => $data['fellowPlayers'][4]['teamId'],
            "championId4" => $data['fellowPlayers'][4]['championId'],
            "summonerId5" => $data['fellowPlayers'][5]['summonerId'],
            "teamId5" => $data['fellowPlayers'][5]['teamId'],
            "championId5" => $data['fellowPlayers'][5]['championId'],
            "summonerId6" => $data['fellowPlayers'][6]['summonerId'],
            "teamId6" => $data['fellowPlayers'][6]['teamId'],
            "championId6" => $data['fellowPlayers'][6]['championId'],
            "summonerId7" => $data['fellowPlayers'][7]['summonerId'],
            "teamId7" => $data['fellowPlayers'][7]['teamId'],
            "championId7" => $data['fellowPlayers'][7]['championId'],
            "summonerId8" => $data['fellowPlayers'][8]['summonerId'],
            "teamId8" => $data['fellowPlayers'][8]['teamId'],
            "championId8" => $data['fellowPlayers'][8]['championId'],
            "ingame_level" => $data['stats']['level'],
            "goldEarned" => $data['stats']['goldEarned'],
            "numDeaths" => $data['stats']['numDeaths'],
            "turretsKilled" => $data['stats']['turretsKilled'],
            "minionsKilled" => $data['stats']['minionsKilled'],
            "championsKilled" => $data['stats']['championsKilled'],
            "totalDamageDealt" => $data['stats']['totalDamageDealt'],
            "totalDamageTaken" => $data['stats']['totalDamageTaken'],
            "doubleKills" => $data['stats']['doubleKills'],
            "killingSprees" => $data['stats']['killingSprees'],
            "largestKillingSpree" => $data['stats']['largestKillingSpree'],
            "team" => $data['stats']['team'],
            "win" => $data['stats']['win'],
            "neutralMinionsKilled" => $data['stats']['neutralMinionsKilled'],
            "largestMultiKill" => $data['stats']['largestMultiKill'],
            "physicalDamageDealtPlayer" => $data['stats']['physicalDamageDealtPlayer'],
            "magicDamageDealtPlayer" => $data['stats']['magicDamageDealtPlayer'],
            "physicalDamageTaken" => $data['stats']['physicalDamageTaken'],
            "magicDamageTaken" => $data['stats']['magicDamageTaken'],
            "largestCriticalStrike" => $data['stats']['largestCriticalStrike'],
            "timePlayed" => $data['stats']['timePlayed'],
            "totalHeal" => $data['stats']['totalHeal'],
            "totalUnitsHealed" => $data['stats']['totalUnitsHealed'],
            "assists" => $data['stats']['assists'],
            "item0" => $data['stats']['item0'],
            "item1" => $data['stats']['item1'],
            "item2" => $data['stats']['item2'],
            "item3" => $data['stats']['item3'],
            "item4" => $data['stats']['item4'],
            "item5" => $data['stats']['item5'],
            "item6" => $data['stats']['item6'],
            "magicDamageDealtToChampions" => $data['stats']['magicDamageDealtToChampions'],
            "physicalDamageDealtToChampions" => $data['stats']['physicalDamageDealtToChampions'],
            "totalDamageDealtToChampions" => $data['stats']['totalDamageDealtToChampions'],
            "trueDamageDealtPlayer" => $data['stats']['trueDamageDealtPlayer'],
            "trueDamageDealtToChampions" => $data['stats']['trueDamageDealtToChampions'],
            "trueDamageTaken" => $data['stats']['trueDamageTaken'],
            "wardPlaced" => $data['stats']['wardPlaced'],
            "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle" => $data['stats']['neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle'],
            "neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle" => $data['stats']['neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle'],
            "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt" => $data['stats']['totalTimeCrowdControlDealt']
        ));
```

Here is the error I am receiving.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 111' in
```

What would be the best way of trying to debug this error? It would be extremly difficult to load dummy data in phpMyAdmin for any hopes of a more detailed error message. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add misisig close bracket )

line 111 is

```
:totalTimeCrowdControlDealt
```

and you didnt close values part

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess the size of he query resulting in the error spooked me a bit which led me to look over the basics.